# Java Mail Change port in Transport without Authentication username and password

Tags: java, email, smtp

Instead of port 25 I want to be able to set the port to be whatever I want, along with the host. But I do not want to set the username or password because credentials will vary. My code base was working fine just using the static method Transport.send() to perform the task of sending out emails.
Transport has a connect method with no arguments or a method host/port/auth credentials.
There does not seem to be a way to set just the port and host without using the other two.
Transport seems to default to 25 no matter what I try. I am using a tool called smtp4dev to listen on ports that I am testing.
The important bits of the code are below:

```
    Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");//Just using localhost for testing
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 3500);//Whatever port
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    session = Session.getInstance(props);
    msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(); //transport.connect("localhost", 3500, "","");
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
```

I can inspect session and see that it has the port property set in it, but when I inspect transport I only see the defaultPort as being set. I tried using a blank username, and password to no avail. Any ideas? Am I doing something dumb?

Comment: I'd say your properties are completely ignored. Can you start your JVM with a debugger and tell if that's the case?

Comment: Yep that is the case, but I'm not sure how to set them. I thought that it would be "session.getTransport("smtp");" that would do that.

Comment: I may be onto something, using SMTPTransport instead of Transport. But now the error is that the connection is refused on the port I set. Which may mean it's fixed? http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=javamail&state=class&package=com.sun.mail.smtp&class=SMTPTransport#627

Answer (score 0):

This is what fixed it, just use SMTPTransport instead and it works. I also used port as a string instead of an int.(I then had to unblock the port)

```
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");//Just using localhost for testing
    props.setProperty(SMTP_PORT_PROPERTY, String.valueOf(3500));//Whatever port
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    session = Session.getInstance(props);
    msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(); //transport.connect("localhost", 3500, "","");
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The data type of the property value "mail.smtp.port" must be string.

Try changing this:

```
props.put ("mail.smtp.port", 3500);
```

to:

```
props.put ("mail.smtp.port", "3500");
```